# when does not touch for a while activity?

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have a screen and if a user goes there and does nothing, the screen should close after 15 seconds, but if the user starts to input something the wait time must now increase before the screen is closed.

```
private static long V_Time = 1000 * 15;
Handler handlerUI = new Handler();
.
.
.
handlerUI.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       finish();
    }
}, V_Time);
```

This code of mine closes the screen after 15 seconds even though a user may still be trying to input something. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all 15 seconds is a very short time span! Also consider a confirmation message so the user can still resume if desired.

You can use the [onUserInteraction():void](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) method from Activity to reset your timer on every user interaction detected.

**From the api**

> onUserInteraction() 
>   Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event is dispatched to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample and **reset timer each time the user touched the screen**:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
long delay = 1000 * 15;

protected void onTouch() {
        try {

            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ActDocumentDetails.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            finishActivity();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }, delay );

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```